# Monitoring docker pull progress while using docker compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm starting my container with `docker compose up -d`. Unfortunately, `docker compose logs -f` does not start until the corresponding containers are launched, so it isn't showing the download progress as I would be able to see when using `docker compose up`.

So is there an other way to see the image's download progress?

Comment: `-d` doesn't suppress the image pull progress, last I checked

Comment: Yeah, the images are still downloaded, but I'm unable to see the state of the download process. This is an issue especially if the image is huge, as I don't know if the image is still pulling and the container's log just hasn't started yet or if something else doesn't work.

Comment: The only option I see so far is to look at the network traffic. But that doesn't give me the pull progress in terms of percentages.